# how does ptrace catch fork's system call?

Tags: c++, c, linux, ptrace

I try to use ptrace to catch child process system call id such as execve(11) or fork(2).

my code is here.

```
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/reg.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    pid_t pid;
    if ((pid = fork()) == 0){
        ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);
        pid_t t = fork();
    } else{
        int status;
        struct rusage resource;
        while (true){
            wait4(pid, &status, 0, &resource);
            if (WIFEXITED(status)) break;
            int syscall = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER, pid, 4 * ORIG_EAX, NULL);
            if (syscall == SYS_execve) printf("%d\n", syscall);
            ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, NULL, NULL);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In my opinion, the program should print "2" to screen(because system call "fork" id is 2), but I got nothing after the program finished.
Can someone explain me about it?

Comment: Wait, so you're forking, *waiting for the child to finish*, tracing it *after it finishes*, and then are surprised `ptrace` doesn't show it forking?

Comment: It's my fault. the code "ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);" should be added. I want to catch the fork system call when "pid_t t = fork()." executed.

Answer (score 1):

If your program has exited normally, then

```
if (WIFEXITED(status)) break;
```

this statement might have caused not printing 2 as it is taking it out of the loop.

Please see this statement.

Comment: sorry for my fault. "ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);" should be added to the program. When "pid_t t = fork()" executed, the wait4() function would not block the parent process, and then I use "ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER, pid, 4 * ORIG_EAX, NULL);" to get system call。

Answer (score 0):

Op probably doesn't need the answer now but someone else might so I will just put it out there.

First of all the line `if (syscall == SYS_execve)` will be valid only if you are executing the `execv` system call. This means it will print the system call number assigned to execv which in my machine (x86) is number `11`. But you never actually call execv so nothing gets printed.

Secondly, the reason you probably will not see `2` getting printed on the screen is that if you are using version 2.3.3 or newer, then a `fork()` call isn't actually a system call.
Instead of invoking the `kernel's fork()`, the `glibc fork()` wrapper function is invoked which really isn't a system call.

This function will then invoke the `clone()` system call. So you will need to search for the clone system call id (depending on the version you are using) or use SYS_clone, if you want to catch it and manipulate it.

source: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html